# Resonance sweep Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

Any suggestions on how I can implement resonance sweeping to find resonant frequency with a micro controller? 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjVFKYE6Y-g

Comment: What are you trying to find the resonant frequency of?

Comment: Sweeping a frequency is easy.  Detecting resonance is probably more tricky.  However, in either case this can't be done without some real specs.

Comment: ITs an LC Circuit. The Voltage is an AC Voltage, stepped down using a voltage divider. So it can be set to any small voltage.

Comment: Being part of a true resonating LC circuit is not what your GPIO-pins are designed for, but if you are willing to test that anyway, how about: connecting LC in parallel, with one side connected to ground, then briefly pull the other node high with an GPIO-pin and turn the GPIO pin in high impedance mode. Then measure the time between the zero crossings that should occur at least couple times. Might need a series resistor to reduce the dampening by the clamping diodes.

Comment: Can you describe, how would I use zero crossing for this?